# Discrete-time lowpass filter with rapid response to significative changes in the input

Tags: discrete-mathematics, signal-processing, filters

I have a signal that looks like this:

[image]

To obtain an average, I apply this formula

```
y[i] = α * x[i] + (1-α) * y[i-1]
```

With a relatively small value of **α** the output is “stable“ enough for my application, the problem is that the output responds very slow to significative changes in the input

[image]

So, I sort of solved the problem with a variable **α** that depends on the normalised input like this

```
normalised_input[i] = abs(x[i] - y[i-1]) / y[i-1]

α = α_fast * normalized_input + α_slow * (1 - normalized_input)
```

**α** is the linear interpolation between a **α_fast** that responds quickly to significative changes in the input and a **α_slow** that gives the average I want.

I suspect there is a better way to do this, so I wonder what is the most common approach to this kind of problem.

Comment: Why can't you just using a moving average FIR filter? What advantage does this IIR implementation have?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I want to make it's implementation as simple as posible, without storing a set of previous values for the N-stage delay, but just the previous value.